# MySQL Joining table that must contain certain values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that contains people. Those people are assigned one or more people types. People types are stored in different MySQL table and I use joins to link the data.

What I want to do is select people within specific types.

In my example below, I want to select people who are in the people type `1234` AND `4321`. They can be in other people types too, but they must be in at least the two I've specified.

Here's my query I've tried but it returns nothing.

```
SELECT p.person_id
    FROM people AS p 
    INNER JOIN people_types AS pt ON pt.person_id = p.person_id AND pt.type_id IN ('1234') AND pt.type_id IN ('4321')
```

Is there a specific function that should allow me to do this?

---

*EDIT*

I've been recommend joining the table twice. But this seems inefficient. What if I used a `LEFT JOIN` instead, would that provide more flexibility?

```
SELECT p.person_id
    FROM people AS p 
    LEFT JOIN people_types AS pt ON pt.person_id = p.person_id
    WHERE pt.type_id IN ('1234') AND pt.type_id IN ('4321'
```

Comment: I think you will need to join same table twice.

Comment: Using left join & keeping your ID's in where condition is same like  IN clause suggested in few answers. Condition will be always false. One row will belong to only one type. Your AND in Where checks for type_id column of one row for two values, which will be false always.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that person should be in both types which you have specified, then you need to join PersonTypes twice.
I think this should work,

```
SELECT p.person_id
    FROM people AS p 
    INNER JOIN people_types AS pt ON pt.person_id = p.person_id AND pt.type_id IN ('1234')
    INNER JOIN people_types AS pt1 ON pt1.person_id = p.person_id AND pt1.type_id IN ('4321')
```

To avoid join,

```
select PersonID,count(id) from PersonType
where TypeID in(1,2)
group by PersonID 
having count(id) >= 2
```

See Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fe99/1)

Comment: Thanks @AK47. I'd be interested to know if it's possible without making a second table join. Seems inefficient.

Comment: Sure I will try, Hope values in your values in PeopleType are UNIQUE means one person & one type will be only one time, no duplicate rows in table. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I'll give it a test and see how I go! Will let you know!

Comment: @BenSinclair, I have updated my answer. Please check.